# download.file in R programming

Tags: r

I tried to download file from function "download.file" and I find this problem when I tried to write this code

```
fileurl1<-"https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
download.file(fileUrl1, destfile = "./C:/Users/DELL/Desktop")
```

> Error in download.file(fileUrl1, destfile = "./C:/Users/DELL/Desktop") : 
>     cannot open destfile './C:/Users/DELL/Desktop', reason 'Invalid argument'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destination needs to be a path to csv file and not to the folder. Try :

```
download.file(fileurl1, './C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/temp.csv')
```